# Why is process_resident_memory_bytes{job="prometheus"} showing no data points?

Tags: prometheus, metrics, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

I've just gotten started with prometheus locally and while it runs and I can see most metrics, I can't see process_resident_memory_bytes.

All the set up I've done so far is download prometheus and edit my YAML like so:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 10s
scrape_configs:
 - job_name: prometheus
   static_configs:
    - targets:
       - localhost:9090
 - job_name: node
   static_configs:
    - targets:
      - localhost:9100
```

When I search for the process_resident_memory_bytes metric, I see nothing and executing it as a query shows 'No data points found'

Can anyone explain if I'm missing an additional set up step?

I'm using prometheus-2.26.0.darwin-amd64.tar.gz.

Comment: I see that you are scraping port 9100 so I suppose you are scraping from node exporter. For me node exporter has had some weird bugs. Can you provide some more info like OS, kernel version. Also does the metric return 0 or doesn't exist at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are running on macOS, as noted by your use of the `prometheus-2.26.0.darwin-amd64.tar.gz` tarball. As a Prometheus developer notes in [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/12899#issuecomment-827819663) those `process_...` metrics are not available on the Darwin/macOS platform at this time. This would include the metric you mentioned: `process_resident_memory_bytes`.

Comment: Exactly, this seems to be the problem. Same issue here: in macOS there is no way of getting this metric, but same application in Linux populates this metric without any change.